# How can i change the role type as a varchar in FOS

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working with FosUserBundle, in my Symfony2 project , I would like to know how to change the role as a text and not an array(I mean I have the role as a varchar not as a table in my database), is that possible?

In the abstract class user I have already change the type as string.

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $roles;
```

here is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROlE_Client:      ROLE_Client
    ROlE_Agent:       ROLE_Agent
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            #always_use_default_target_path: false
            #default_target_path:            /affichage
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/affichage, role: ROLE_Agent }
```

Comment: Just don't do that !! 1st it's not by changing a doc annotation, you're changing the type in your entity. 2nd you'll broke all the security methods of symfony

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily break the security, as long as you returned an array from `getRoles()` you would be fine (`return array($this->roles);` would be easy enough). Why are you wanting to change the field type though? What is your thinking behind it?

Comment: i have two types of roles (agent and client ) if i register a user as an agent , i will have [ROLE_AGENT, ROLE_USER] and otherwise , when i used the access_control :  - { path: ^/affichage, role: ROLE_Agent } its not working .. it gave me acces denied

Comment: Can you paste in your question your security.yml ? And i don't know if it's normal but it's `ROLE_AGENT` and not `ROLE_Agent` in your access control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to change your `role_hierarchy` by doing :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_CLIENT:      ROLE_USER
    ROLE_AGENT:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Respect the normalization by using caps.

To explain why it's like that : 
The key is the name of the role and the value is of what is inherited

example :

```
ROLE_AGENT: ROLE_USER #An agent has agent's rights + user's rights
```